# Amazon EC2 + Windows Server 2008 + Memcached = how?

Tags: windows, memcached, amazon-ec2

We are building a system that would benefit greatly from a Distributed Caching mechanism, like Memcached. But i cant get my head around the configuration of Memcached daemons and clients finding each other on an Amazon Data Center. Do we manually setup the IP addresses of each memcache instance (they wont be dedicated, they will run on Web Servers or Worker Boxes) or is there a automagic way of getting them to talk to each other? I was looking at Microsoft Windows Server App Fabric Caching, but it seems to either need a file share or a domain to work correctly, and i have neither at the moment... given internal IP addresses are Transient on Amazon, i am wondering how you get around this...

Comment: So, looking around at some other things, it seems that DNS might be a way around this. anyone tried Memcached with DNS? we have an External DNS provider (Zerigo) who provide an API for updating our domain. looking into this in the next few days. am i embarking up the wrong tree, or would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't setup a cluster of memcached servers before, but Membase is a solution that could take away all of the pain you are experiencing with memcached. Membase is basically memcached with a persistence layer underneath and comes with great cluster management software. Clustering servers together is as easy since all you need to do is tell the cluster what the ip address of the new node is. If you already have an application written for Memcached it will also work with Membase since Membase uses the Memcached protocol. It might be worth taking a look at.

Comment: I am liking the look of this MemBase thing. thanks for the link. seems to be easier to manage than MemcacheD.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could create an elastic ip in EC2 for each of the boxes that hold your memcached servers.  These elastic ips can be dynamically mapped to any EC2 instance.  Then your memcached clients just use the elastic ips as if they were static ip addresses.

http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-elastic-ip-internal

Comment: I have managed to get around using external IPs for this by using Zerigo's DNS service. I have a windows service that runs on all machines and updates a DNS record. all machines then know which DNS record to look for when looking for SQL Server, Solr, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you seemed to have discovered, Route53 is commonly used for these discovery purposes. For your specific use case, however, I would just use [Amazon ElasticCache](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/). Amazon has both memcached and redis compliant versions of ElasticCache and they manage the infrastructure for you including providing you with a DNS entry point.  Also for managing things like asp.net session state, you might consider [this](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/managing-aspnet-session-state-with-dynamodb) article on the DynamoDB session state provider.

General rule of thumb: if you are developing a new app then try and leverage what the cloud provides vs. build it, it'll make your life way simpler.